# The background color of xcb window is black

Tags: background, xcb

```
#include <unistd.h>      /* pause() */

#include <xcb/xcb.h>

int
main ()
{
    /* Open the connection to the X server */
    xcb_connection_t *connection = xcb_connect (NULL, NULL);


    /* Get the first screen */
    const xcb_setup_t      *setup  = xcb_get_setup (connection);
    xcb_screen_iterator_t   iter   = xcb_setup_roots_iterator (setup);
    xcb_screen_t           *screen = iter.data;


    /* Create the window */
    xcb_window_t window = xcb_generate_id (connection);
    xcb_create_window (connection,                    /* Connection          */
                       XCB_COPY_FROM_PARENT,          /* depth (same as root)*/
                       window,                        /* window Id           */
                       screen->root,                  /* parent window       */
                       0, 0,                          /* x, y                */
                       150, 150,                      /* width, height       */
                       10,                            /* border_width        */
                       XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT, /* class               */
                       screen->root_visual,           /* visual              */
                       0, NULL );                     /* masks, not used yet */


    /* Map the window on the screen */
    xcb_map_window (connection, window);


    /* Make sure commands are sent before we pause so that the window gets shown */
    xcb_flush (connection);


    pause ();    /* hold client until Ctrl-C */

    xcb_disconnect (connection);

    return 0;
}
```

I have a demo of xcb(copied from internet). In some linux platforms, it shows a window with transparent background, but other linux platfomts, it show a window filling with black background. what can I do to set default background color to transparent?

I read the reference of xcb, it said If XCB_BACK_PIXMAP_NONE is specified, the window has no defined background. The server may fill the contents with the previous screen contents or with contents of its own choosing. I don't know how to set x server then it will fill the contents of the previous screen contents.

Comment: "Previous screen contents" is not the same thing as "transparent". (E.g. when the contents of whatever is below your window changes). Which of those two things do you actually want? The short answer to your question is "that's not possible". The long answer is complicated.

Comment: Thanks @Uli Schlachter.In some linux platforms, If I show window or dialog implementing with Qt, it will show a black background then it becomes normal window or dialog. The experience is bad. I read the implements of Qt, in linux platforms it uses xcb to implement window. If I can config the x server to set xcb window to be transparent or set the contents with previous screen contents, I think it can resovle my problem.

Comment: Qt already instructs the X11 server not to draw a background. (first `mask` is `XCB_CW_BACK_PIXMAP` and it is set to `XCB_BACK_PIXMAP_NONE` in `values`): https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/a8c04721afd4457b4590db892bb246918dab1076/src/plugins/platforms/xcb/qxcbwindow.cpp#L336 I would guess that the black comes from a compositing manager like pixcom, xcompmgr, ....

Comment: Also, according to https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html#requests:CreateWindow a background of `None` is the default. So your program should already show the same behaviour as Qt.